# Parallel http post requests (Multithreading) C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, http, concurrency, parallel-processing

How can I make, for example 10 parallel http post requests in c# (send them at the same time)? I'm using xNet library to work with requests and response. Here's code:

```
private void getUsersFromGroup(string groupId)
        {
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
            HttpResponse res;
            string resStr;

            rp["offset"] = "0";
            rp["count"] = "1000";
            rp["online"] = "1";                
            rp["group_id"] = groupId;                
            rp["access_token"] = access_token;
            rp["v"] = apiVersion;
            res = request.Post(Api + "users.search", rp);
            resStr = res.ToString();

            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(resStr);
            if (obj.response.count != 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in obj.response.items)
                {
                        if (!usersID.Contains(item.id))
                        {
                            usersID.Add(item.id);
                        }

                }

            }

        }
```

Im calling this method in foreach loop btw, maybe it would change something.

```
public void getUsers()
        {
            foreach (string groupID in groups)
            {
                getUsersFromGroup(groupID);
            }
        }
```

I want to be able to send 3 API request every second. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried to use Parallel.ForEach: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Will Parallel Foreach give me same speed advantage as 10 or 20 parallel http requests?

Comment: You can set the MaxDegreeOfParallelism property of Parallel.ForEach explicitly to manage the number of parallel requests.

Comment: I wanted to understand will result be the same if I make many parallel http requests or I make parallel foreach?

Comment: The performance would be kinda the same, but with Parallel.ForEach has some perks like the caller thread can treat it as a synchronous block, and we can wrap the Parallel.ForEach inside try-catch blocks too.

Comment: How can I limit to 3 requests per second?

Comment: Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en/us/library/hh696703(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use ThreadPool you may run you method on separated threads like this:

```
foreach (var groupId in groupIds) {
    var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => getUsersFromGroup(groupId));
    thread.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely try Task.WhenAll. Sample code can look like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<UserDto>> GetUsersInParallel(IEnumerable<int> userIds)
{
    var tasks = userIds.Select(id => client.GetUser(id));
    var users = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return users;
} 

public async Task<UserDto> GetUser(int id)
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://youraddress/api/users/" + id)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
    var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDto>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

    return user;
}
```

For full analysis and more code go to my blog post: http://www.michalbialecki.com/2018/04/19/how-to-send-many-requests-in-parallel-in-asp-net-core/